# weird behavior of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build, navigator

I'm using trying to get current location using geolocation plugin, I'm using phonegap build, and enabled debugging as well.

Every time when the app opens all the code works and stops right at the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation line.
the weinre console doesn't give me any error. But when I type the same line in the console it works and finds the location without any problem.

I tried it with the bare bones app and its the same behavior,

here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// Cordova is ready
//

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
// onSuccess Geolocation
//

function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' + 'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' + 'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br />' + 'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '<br />' + 'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' + 'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br />' + 'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br />' + 'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '<br />';
}
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

it doesn't fail, it just stops. I put the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in a if (navigator.geolocation) block, it doesn't give me any errors, it just stops.

if you want the weinre debug link and the apk of the barebones app, I can link it here.

Here is the apk, that should run on an android device
http://s3.amazonaws.com/android.phonegap/slicehost-production/apps/947473/Anil-debug.apk

and here is the weinre debug link, http://debug.build.phonegap.com/client/#a9d1c370-eb2a-11e3-80a2-22000b211b97

it should give you the geolocation coords right after the app starts, but it doesn't work,
but, you can make it work from the weinre console,
as soon as you run this command in the console

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

the app gives you the coords on the phone.
If you want to look at all the code in detail here is the github link as well
https://github.com/syllogismos/phonegap-gmaps

Answer (score 1):

- I am not using Phonegap build
- I made a setup where I load all the files properly [Github](https://github.com/mboeckle/wikilocation)
- Feel free to fork

Hope this helps, let me know if it works. It also could be a problem with phonegap built.

If you want to try out it with Eclipse ([Eclipse-Phonegap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html))

[image]

best

M